# How to custom built-in attribute tag helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I want to custom built-in input tag helper. By default input asp-for attribute generate some boiler plate code like Id, data-val, and so on. my problem with this kind, i can't custom input name. like i want it to be name="q". asp-forattribute add name attribute same as model property name. If property Username. In input tag name="Username". and the other asp-for add id attribute with property name too. i want to remove it.

User Model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z_.0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+${4,}", ErrorMessage = "Char should start with a letter. Char end with letter and number and minimun length 4 char")
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Page Model

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
  [BindProperty]
  public User Credential { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" autofocus />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't wanna `asp-for` generate Id attribute and the value in `Name` attribute is not the property name?

Comment: If you write an explicit `<input asp-for="Username" name="q">` then the name will not be overwritten by the tag helper. Though you will probably want to `[BindProperty(Name="q")]` as well. You can customise how names are generated by replacing the `IHtmlGenerator` service, and how names are bound by adding a `IBindingMetadataProvider`.